# Sort an array and get the keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays
First Array :

```
$array_1 = array('50','20','30');
```

Second Array :

```
$array_2 = array('50','30','20');
```

Second array is generating by applying `rsort` to `$array_1`

How can i get another array of key like

```
$key_array = ('0','2','1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rsort](http://php.net/rsort) function will reindex your array keys:

> Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys.

You can use [arsort](http://php.net/arsort) instead to maintain index associations. Then you can simply use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) to get your desired result.

```
$unsorted = [50, 20, 30];          // array with unsorted values
$in_reverse = $unsorted;           // create copy because arsort is by reference
arsort($in_reverse);               // do the actual sorting
$keys = array_keys($in_reverse);   // fetch the keys

print_r($keys);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you...i figure it out.

Comment: Please check i changed the output

Comment: @alialwafaa please dont do that. All of the answers on this page are for the required output [0, 2, 1]. When you change your question this way, you obsolete all of the answers. I have rolled back your edit. Please ask another question instead. And when you do, make sure to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rsort` use `arsort`, which

> Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association.

After that - use `array_keys`:

```
$array_1 = array('50','20','30');
arsort($array_1);
print_r(array_keys($array_1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function instead of [rsort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rsort.php) to keep the array keys. After that you'll have the possibilty to use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$array_1 = array('50','20','30');
$array_2 = $array_1;
arsort($array_2);
$key_array = array_keys($array_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like this to sort with saved indexes:

```
$array_1 = array('50','20','30');
arsort($array_1);

$key_array = array_keys($array_1);
var_dump($key_array);
```

output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **array_keys()** function.

```
$array = array('50','30','20');

$arr_keys = array_keys($array);
```